# JProfiler equivalent for Python

Tags: python, performance, optimization, profiling, jprofiler

Please suggest JProfiler equivalent for Python 3+.

The key need is the visualization of methods invocation stack with cumulative time duration (aim is performance optimization)

There is an ideal example of a visualization that I'm looking for:
[image]